# SQL order by "id" causing duplicates while ordering by another column works fine

Tags: mariadb

i have a strange issue with an SQL query using (10.3.2-MariaDB-10.3.2+maria~jessie)

**Query 1**

```
select `reseaus`.`id`, `reseaus`.`nom`
from `reseaus`
where `reseaus`.`id` in (
    select `faces`.`reseau_id`
    from `faces`
    where `faces`.`zone_id` = 14
)
order by `reseaus`.`id` desc
```

**Output**

```
id  nom 
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit
```

[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzWfD.png)

if i change the "sort by id desc" to "sort by nom desc", i get the expected results

```
id  nom
233 Toiles Tendues 4,5m² Hall Public    
232 Toiles Tendues 18m² Salle Départ    
231 Toiles Tendues 18m² Extérieur   
230 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Gauche  
229 Toiles Tendues 18m² Entrée Gare Droit   
228 Toile Tendue Scanner    
227 Toile tendue mur Sogral (Sud)   
222 Toile Tendue 9 m² Arrivée International
```

[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpRK0.png)

Any ideas ?

**SOLVED**
Updating version to 10.4.0-MariaDB-1:10.4.0+maria~bionic solved the problem

Comment: What data type is `id`?

Comment: MariaDB-10.3.2 was a very early beta release in the 10.3 series. update to a later version.

Comment: @Uueerdo id is the primary key int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Is it possible the tool you are using to run the SQL is showing only the first 8 rows? The result looks good, if it considers only the first few rows.

Comment: @TheImpaler no way, i did test with **phpmyadmin**, my **php script** and **mysql console**, same strange result

Comment: Have you tried with something like MySQL Workbench? Also, are you absolutely sure that is the query you are executing? A `SELECT stuff FROM a_single_table` should never be able to repeat the table's auto-incremented PK field; not matter how it is ordered, or what is in the WHERE. Actually.... that query should never return more than one row at all.

Comment: Can you count the resulting rows? Change the first line for `select count(*)`. I think it won't give you `8` as you expect, but a bigger number instead.

Comment: @TheImpaler **select count(*)** give me 8 results in all cases, i will try to upgrade my mariadb version and see

Comment: Ignore that last sentence of my comment, I misread at the end of my edit time; the rest still applies though.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the sql **EXPLAIN** of both queries but i dont know how to read them, @Uueerdo i don't have MySql Workbench, i dont think it is a tool related issue since i did test with the mysql console, phpmyadmin and my php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=da1138740b30685b84607f390dd33169), the problem doesn't occur in 10.3.11.

Given 10.3.2 was an early beta isn't not surprising it had a bug.

Comment: i updated to **10.4.0-MariaDB-1:10.4.0+maria~bionic** and it works all fine, thank you for your support

Comment: warning 10.4.0. is also a beta version. Report any bugs on jira.mariadb.org.